# Sharing session between React front-end server and PHP/Symfony back-end server

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, session, authentication

I have an application with consists of a front-end server running React and a back-end server running PHP/Symfony. Part of the front-end is developed using twig templates (mostly backoffice forms for updating content) and is handled by the same back-end server, and part of it is developed using React and resides in the separated front-end server (for public user access, with some more functionality).

The system has three user roles: a superadmin (authenticated through a form against an in-memory user configured in Symfony), backoffice employee (authenticated through the same form against the User entity in the database) and a "public user" sort of speak, which uses the public side of the application, authenticated through a third party service which, in the end, requires us to start a session inside one of our APIs with a code similar to this:

```
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($publicUserEntity, null, 'main', $publicUserEntity->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

Users are successfully authenticated in the three ways, but session is only open if I am in the backend server and not if I make a request from the frontend server.

For example, after I login with a Public User, if I make a request to:

```
http://backendserverhost/api/someentity/me
```

That API loads the current session's User Id to get the user's data, and I get a proper response according to the authenticated user.

But if I make the same request from the frontend server (to the same API, and same endpoint) in order to get the same information and show it, it returns an error as if it was an anonymous user.

What changes should I do to be able to "use" the opened session in the backend server to make the frontend server requests?

Comment: You need to pass some sort of token to the server(to verify it's the authenticated user) every time you make a request to the server.

Comment: @Frosty619 I was thinking of using an ApiKeyAuthenticator according to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html

But that requires adding that form of authentication as a new feature. Is there no configuration option regarding permissions or session cookies to allow this without adding this functionality?

Comment: You could use a cookie based authentication approach, although that has it's own problems. You can read about the difference between cookie and token based approach here (https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/). 
You do have to add an authentication feature on the backend; you can create a class `Auth` and use a method like: `Auth::isUserAuthenticated($token)` for every request to the server.

Comment: Thanks! That post oriented me a lot, I used cookie-based authentication so far, but I'll implement token-based authentication in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding two different solutions, based on all suggestions:

**Cookie-based authentication** (the one I am using right now): I start the session in the controller as shown above, and obtain the session ID. I send it to the React front-end server in the query, and they use it in their requests as the "PHPSESSID" Cookie in order to authenticate.

```
    //Assign session to user
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($userEntity, null, 'main', $userEntity->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

    //Redirect to homepage
    $redirectUrl = $this->container->getParameter('zafter_login_redirect_url');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl . '?login=' . $this->get('session')->getId());
    $cookie = new Cookie('PHPSESSID', $this->get('session')->getId());
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    return $response;
```

This proved to be the fastest and simplest way to solve the problem, since it requires little coding, no new dependencies or bundles, and I only had to modify the response in the login API.

**Token-based authentication** (the one I will probably end up using, since it is also useful for the mobile client): Using a bundle that implements JWT authentication (such as LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) I generate an authentication token after login, send it in the request, and the client (either React or Mobile) uses it to authenticate in subsecuent requests.

The process is detailed in the bundle's documentation: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Comment: Thank you. How do you then authenticate on each AJAX request with your PHPSESSID? Do you have to pass it in the header of your request?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a token for the user and pass it as an argument at each request.

Using the FOSOAuthRestBundle you can define an Accesstoken in your user model class and use it to authenticate at each request.

They have a pretty good tutorial here:  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using cookie-based authentication for the moment, but I will end up implementating token-based authentication for sure.