# Most secure way to pass authorised user from Laravel backend to frontend with React

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, redux

I am building a weather app with laravel(almost finished) and i decided to implement the frontend with react/redux/react-router and use laravel from api calls. The only thing that i decided to leave the same is my custom laravel auth implementation with routes and views. However, i struggle to find a secure way to pass my Auth::user object after login in order to store on redux. I have 2 options:

1) After login and before render the main jsx, to make an axios request to specific route in order to return the Auth::user like:

in routes.php

```
Route::post('/auth/user' ,function(){
   return response()->json(['user'=>auth()->user()]);
})->middleware('auth');
```

in js

```
axios.post('/auth/user').then((res)=>{console.log(res.data.user)}).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)})
```

2) pass Auth::user with blade, catch it with getAttribute, save it to redux and instantly remove from DOM:

```
<div id="app" data-usr="{{ auth()->user() }}"></div>
```

However neither of them seem to me like a secure way to pass this kind of data. Can anyone tell me his opinion about this or figure me with a better solution?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you want to expose to the frontend?

Comment: You mean after i store it to redux or before?

Comment: Assume that whatever you send to the frontend will be abused by attackers. Send only necessary information - this means you should be cherry-picking the fields you want to expose instead of sending the whole `auth()->user()` over.

Comment: Understood but, what about an axios call with a hashed token. This isn't secure enough?

Comment: Not sure why you are creating separate "hashed tokens" - is [PHP Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) not enough for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use them inside react i suppose

Comment: [Yes you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776363/1049833)

Comment: Thanks a lot! i haven't thought about it, i'd definitely check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully i found a solution with API TOKEN implementation built-in with Laravel. Also i destroy token after logout and recreate it in login, so nobody can use it with other services to collect data if he is not signed in

Comment: Can you explain that further?

Comment: when user logs in a new token is created and updates user's api_token column, passed through blade view with window.Laravel and appends to axios.header. So with every request from user to api, the api_token is checked. if false token or missing no data returned

Comment: Please add such explanation to the answer by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Class to represent the user with just the vital information I need to show on the front-end.

So instead of passing `auth->user()` to the front, you can inject it into a `decorator` and generate a `simpler user class` with just the methods you wish to display.

Comment: Or use a Resource Class to transform your user to the simple version. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources

Comment: @commonsense genius! Had no idea! :D
Go for this one instead!!